# Secure Azure Function in Xamarin Forms app.How should it work?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-functions

In my xamarin forms app I have the need to call some azure functions in a secure way.

What I have done

1. All my functions have AuthorizationLevel=Function
2. Get Function Key by making a call to a webApi that is stored on the server
3. Function Key is passed in the header of the http call (all works!!)

**I do not like the above and definitely I do not want to store the function key on the mobile app as an alternative**

I have read about Authentication/Authorization but I cannot figure out if it fits my scenario

**My Scenario**

Ability to call an azure function in a secure way.User should **NOT** be prompted to login.**Its a silent call.**

1. Is there some sort of accessToken I can use and retrieve safely from
   azure portal and use that in some way to access the function?
2. How do you securely access an azure function in a mobile app?
3. Any samples? I have read below and did not help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

**Edited**

Tried below but I get an error(connection string error) in the mobile app.Also not sure how it works when deployed as in debug it uses the credential of the developer
[image]

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient =
        new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("mysecretIdentifier").ConfigureAwait(false);
    var key = secret.Value;
```

Comment: does the function do anything that is specific to a mobile user or it does not matter?

Comment: it does not matter , it just retrieve a json from a blob.

Comment: @developer9969 are you already use Azure ActiveDirectory authentification  within your mobile app ?

Comment: @HoussemDbira I can use AAD no problem but must be a silent call a user should not be prompted to login using those providers.Reading a value from the vault would be fine but not sure how it works in production see edited question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Recommended Approach

The best way to handle authentication for Azure Functions is to leverage the [built-in Authentication and Authorization feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization?WT.mc_id=azurefunctions-stackoverflow-bramin). This uses an existing auth provider to authenticate your users allowing you to avoid creating/storing/maintaining user ids & passwords.

Here's a walkthrough adding Azure AD B2C Authentication to Azure Functions: https://github.com/jimbobbennett/MobileAppsOfTomorrow-Lab/blob/master/Workshop/2-SetupAzureFunctions.md#4-setup-function-app-authentication

#### Alternative Approach

Since it sounds like you aren't using authentication and you want to have a secure API that only your app can access, we can use `AuthorizationLevel=Function` and inject the API key into our app using our Continuous Integration server at build-time.

I do this for my [GitTrends](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends) app. Here's how:

- Create a `AzureConstants.cs` that will store the Functions API Key: https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/master/GitTrends.Shared/Constants/AzureConstants.cs
- Use `git update-index --assume-unchanged AzureConstants.cs` to ensure the API Keys aren't committed into source control: https://www.jimbobbennett.io/hiding-api-keys-from-git/
- On your Continous Integration Server, Add the API Keys as Environment Variables. Here's how to do it in [App Center](https://appcenter.ms?WT.mc_id=azurefunctions-stackoverflow-bramin): [https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/build/custom/variables/](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/build/custom/variables/?WT.mc_id=azurefunctions-stackoverflow-bramin)
- Add a pre-build script to your Continuous Integration server to inject the API Keys. Here's the pre-build script I use in App Center Build for GitTrends: https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/master/GitTrends.iOS/appcenter-pre-build.sh

Comment: Thank you very much for your time,learned a lot from you on async!.
We authenticate against a database and cannot use any of the providers.
I did look at your gittrends app but somebody can still decompile the apk and get the keys.
I would like to store the functionkey in the vault and then use the code in edited section but I get an error in the mobile app
Alternative have a .net core api that reads the secret from the vault and return the function key, but then how do I secure the endpoint
any example of xamarin call an api using a certificate ?your suggestion help is really appreciated

Comment: the bottom line i want to make a  secure call to an azure function from a xamarin forms app,without storing any keys in the app.Cannot believe there is no a safe way todo this

Comment: The only secure way to do it is to use Azure Functions’ Authentication/Authorization feature. Every other way requires you to hardcode the API key into the app. Even if you used Azure Key Vault, you would need to hardcode its connection string into your app.

Comment: thank you at least I know where I stand now.To be absolutely clear with Authentication/Authorization is always "interactive" there is no silent authentication?. I am after some sort of silent auth.Many thanks anyway

Comment: No problem! When you get a chance, don’t forget to mark this as “Answered” to help fellow devs with the same question in the future. Right - eventually the user has to authenticate which requires a username/password or a token. A silent authentication would only work if the user had already authenticated elsewhere and you were able to access that existing auth token.